# minimal initramfs (with root on LVM)

Tags: arch-linux, lvm, initramfs-tools

Is it possible to trim the initramfs by excluding the udev hook when root is on an LVM?
LVM2 installations guide(for LVM) from arch [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_Arch_Linux_on_LVM#Adding_mkinitcpio_hooks) sites udev and lvm2 as the the two hooks necessary.

I have managed to trim down my mkinitcpio.conf to:

```
#MODULES=()

BINARIES=(fsck fsck.btrfs btrfsck)

HOOKS=(base udev lvm2)
```

following [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Minimal_initramfs) guide.
If i remove either udev or lvm2 from here, it breaks, the error message is something to the line

```
can't find /dev/linux/arch`
```

which is basically a `device mapper` mapping path.
What i wanted to know is, can i further trim it down and remove the `udev` hook? is there any way that makes it possible ?  The guides i have seen/read so far are generic and (systems without LVM).

Output of `lsinitcpio`:

```
❯ lsinitcpio -a /boot/initramfs-linux-clear.img
==> Image: /boot/initramfs-linux-clear.img
==> Created with mkinitcpio 30
==> Kernel: 5.9.16-1-clear
==> Size: 47.1 MiB

==> Included modules:
  dm-bio-prison           dm-cache                dm-log                  dm-persistent-data      dm-snapshot
  dm-bufio                dm-cache-smq            dm-mirror               dm-region-hash          dm-thin-pool

==> Included binaries:
  blkid                   dmsetup                 journalctl              modprobe                sulogin                 systemd-tmpfiles
  btrfsck                 fsck                    kmod                    mount                   switch_root             udevadm
  busybox                 fsck.btrfs              lvm                     pdata_tools             systemctl               umount
```

Things i tried so far:

- Get the list necessary modules required by adding the
  `break=postmount` boot option to the fallback image and doing
  `'lsmod | awk 'NF==3{print $1}'`. Adding those in the MODULES array.
- Adding all the modules as listed under `Included Modules` from the
  output of `lsinitcpio` (e.g  `dm-bio-prison`,`dm-cache`,`dm-log` etc).

NOTE: i know that the systemd hook can replace the udev hook but that's not what looking for. I want it reduced to just the base and lvm2(if necessary).

Comment: If you're not wedded to that particular distribution, you could use a distro that is already configured & built with size concerns, e.g. Alpine Linux.  Or start from scratch, and use Buildroot to configure & build your custom kernel and initramfs/rootfs.

Comment: @sawdust if it is possible in one distro, it should be possible in another one i guess? does Alpine LInux handle LVM/device mapper in a different way?

Comment: *"if it is possible in one distro, it should be possible in another one i guess?"* -- You guess wrong. Linux distros all use the same Linux kernel, but anything/everything else could be different, not just the GUI but even the C library.